# How to print Alternate A.P and G.P series in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print Alternate A.P and G.P series like:

```
- 2 2 4 6 6 18 8 54 10 162 12 486... i.e (A1 G1 A2 G2 A3 G3 .....)
```

here variable is with literal meaning asinged below.
I found in form of

```
[(2, 2), (4, 6), (6, 18), (8, 54), (10, 162), (12, 486), (14, 1458), 
 (16, 4374), (18, 13122), (20, 39366)]
```

How can I find as expected?

```
a,d,r,length=2,2,3,10
lst=[( a+(n-1)*d, a*r**(n-1) ) for n in range(1,length+12)]
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to [flatten your list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python), you could use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?itertools.chain.from_iterable#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

chn = chain.from_iterable(lst)
flat_tuple = tuple(chn)
print(flat_tuple)  # (2, 2, 4, 6, 6, 18, 8, 54, 10, 162, ...)
```

or if you need that as a string you could to this:

```
from itertools import chain

strg = ' '.join(str(i) for i in chain.from_iterable(lst))
print(strg)  # 2 2 4 6 6 18 8 54 10 162 12 486 14 ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. you give me the exact answer to improve my skills.

Comment: Patrick Artner,                                                                                                                         Please, tell me how works itertools chain? Giving an example.

Comment: there are lots of examples in the doc (see link in my answer).